# Equal area projections with different area results in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, equal-area

Using ArcGIS, I have to calculate areas of huge polygons all over the Pacific Oceans betwwen 20N and 30S. I have been trying different Equal-areas projections (Cylindrical and sinusoidal for example) and found different results for the area claculation.

For example, one polygon is having a surface of 1'604'176 km2 with Cylindrical and a surface of 1'605'483 km2 with sinusoidal...

So my questions are:

- Am I correct to use Equal area projections for calculating areas? Should I be using a different type of projections (equidistance...)?
- How can you have different results between the projections and which one should be consider best?
- At last, using an equal area projection, I discover that if I break down a big polygon into 6 smaller polygons and I compare the sum of the areas of the 6 smaller polygons with the area of the big polygon, I have a difference between the values (difference of 60Km2 for a polygon of 1'600'000Km2). How is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is correct to use an equal area projection in order to compute the area of your polygon.

However, in your case, you should be aware that only **the vertices** of a polygon are projected when you change the coordinate system. Between the vertices, straight lines are then interpolated (but if you have a huge polygons, those lines should have been curves), which could explain why your areas are not exactly the same.

In order to avoid this problem, one workaround is to [densify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000003000000) your polygon before you project it. The projection will then be more precise. As mentioned by @whuber, the densification of the polygon should be done in the original coordinate system (the one used when the polygon was digitized) in order to achieve an accurate result.

As a remark, this is also what occurs when you cut your polygon in pieces: cutting will add new vertices.